# Java Swing - DefaultListModel - Printing all object information, when i only want to print one field

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

I have this DefaultListModel

```
DefaultListModel listModel;
//constructor does the right hting... etc.. I skipped over a lot of code
JList jlist_available_items; 
....
jlist_available_items= new JList(cartModel); //etc
```

Everything is working almost perfectly the issue is that

```
listModel.addElement(product);
```

if I change it to product.name it will look correctly, but behave wrongly [the object itself won't be accesisble, only the name]

Is adding the object to the view, and all I want to add is the object name.

When I change it to the name it causes all sorts of issues, because I store the objects in a hashmap, and the hashmap uses objects as keys, not the product.name string.

The reason is so that this method can search the hashmap for the right object.

```
  for (Product p : store.database.keySet()) {
    if (jlist_available_items.getSelectedValuesList().contains(
        (Product) p)) { // if item is selected
        cart.addItem(p);
    }
  }
```

How can I fix this?? I have been trying to fix it and related bugs for almsot two hours = ( !

Also sample output is

```
Product [description=descrion test, name=test]
```

That is what it is printing. I just want it to print the name. = (!

Also the objects are in a hashmap. I can just iterate through the hashmap until an object has the same name value and then use that, but I don't want to. I want a more proper and scalable solution, namely because I am having so much trouble thinking of one.

BY THE WAY! This is a GUI app in Swing! If you want images just ask = )!

EDIT: And now nmy list cell renderer is broken! It was working just a moment ago... = (

```
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        Product product = (Product) value;

        return this;
       }
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer

Comment: forgot to add this.setText... agjsaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `toString()` method of the objects in the model is called to display the list element. And your `Product.toString()` method returns `Product [description=descrion test, name=test]`.

If you want to display something else, then use a ListCellRenderer, as explained in the swing [tutorial about JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer).

EDIT: your renderer has a bug: it doesn't set the text of the returned component (which is a JLabel). It should be:

```
Product product = (Product) value;
setText(product.getName());
return this;
```

Comment: I wrote one that is simple,  but it isn't displaying anything anymore. I changed something that broke it, when I don't use it, it works fine. Mind taking a look, I wil ladd it to the question.